# Run a cron job set up in Wordpress from external source

Tags: wordpress, cron, httprequest

I currently use WP-Crontrol plugin to create, schedule, and run a few cron jobs in a Wordpress environment.  When using this, everything runs smoothly.  My question is:  How can I run the cron job from an external app or http request?

Primarily, I'd like to be able to trigger to run the cron from a Slack /command.  I can't seem to determine what the URL of the request would be, or if this is even possible.

The action hook is "run_post_sync".

Answer (score 0):

No It can't possible.

WP-CRON is Run scheduled callbacks or spawn cron for all scheduled events.

If you want to do like that, you can follow below steps.

1. Create a .php file with wp-load.php in your theme or root folder where you feel secure.

   define("WP_ROOT ", 'var/www/html/');
   require_once WP_ROOT . "wp-load.php";
2. Now you can access all WordPress functionality in this file. So you can write your code, what you want to do with the WordPress.
3. Now you can access or trigger this .php file from outside of WordPress whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I may have misunderstood the requirement initially, which I thought was to initialize a cron schedule, but ultimately what the end goal was... to simply run the function from a Slack /command, in that case I just set up a custom endpoint with the Rest API that runs the function from the Slack command post request.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, REST is best idea. Cool